# Assign actual value after groupby.transform to all rows associate with it. Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to assign name to a new 'responsible' column for all rows associate with `customer`.

If part of the string in 'codes' consist 'manager', manager's name should be assigned to the 'responsible' column. If there is no 'manager' in the codes column, 'responsible' columns should be populated with the 'empl_name' associate with the row.

original `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_name': ['john', 'liza', 'john', 'john', 'liza', 'david', 'john', 'liza', 'david', 'chris'], 
                   'empl_name': ['mike', 'nick', 'kate', 'mike', 'mike', 'kate', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'jennifer'], 
                   'codes': ['empl, office', 'manager_1, remote', 'empl, remote', 'empl, remote', 'empl, office', 
                             'empl, remote', 'empl, remote', 'empl, office', 'empl, remote', 'manager_2, office']})
```

looks like:

```
cust_name   empl_name      codes

john         mike       empl, office                
liza         nick       manager_1, remote             
john         kate       empl, remote                
john         mike       empl, remote                
liza         mike       empl, office                
david        kate       empl, remote                
john         mike       empl, remote                
liza         mike       empl, office                
david        mike       empl, remote 
chris        jennifer   manager_2, office
```

output should be:

```
cust_name   empl_name      codes                responsible

john         mike       empl, office                mike
liza         nick       manager_1, remote           nick
john         kate       empl, remote                kate
john         mike       empl, remote                mike
liza         mike       empl, office                nick
david        kate       empl, remote                kate
john         mike       empl, remote                mike
liza         mike       empl, office                nick
david        mike       empl, remote                mike
chris        jennifer   manager_2, office           jennifer
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a value to a new column:

```
df['manager_name'] = df.loc[df['code']=='manager','empl_name'].iloc[0]
```

Added a case where there is no manager name:

```
names = df[['empl_name', 'code']].drop_duplicates()
df['manager_name'] = names.loc[names['code']=='manager','empl_name'].iloc[0] if len(names)>1 else names.loc[0, 'empl_name']
```

Output:

```
  cust_name empl_name     code manager_name
0      john      mike     empl         nick
1      john      mike     empl         nick
2      john      nick  manager         nick
3      john      mike     empl         nick
4      john      nick  manager         nick
```

**Edit:**

You can groupby `cust_name` and apply a custom function what does what you want:

```
def assign_responsible(x):
    mask = x['codes'].str.contains('manager')
    if sum(mask) > 0:
        x['responsible'] = x.loc[mask, 'empl_name'].iloc[0]
    else:
        x['responsible'] = x['empl_name']
    return x

df = df.groupby('cust_name').apply(assign_responsible)
```

Output:

```
  cust_name empl_name             codes responsible
0      john      mike       empl, office        mike
1      liza      nick  manager_1, remote        nick
2      john      kate       empl, remote        kate
3      john      mike       empl, remote        mike
4      liza      mike       empl, office        nick
5     david      kate       empl, remote        kate
6      john      mike       empl, remote        mike
7      liza      mike       empl, office        nick
8     david      mike       empl, remote        mike
9     chris  jennifer  manager_2, office    jennifer
```

Comment: looks like that works, could you please advise what should I do if there is no manager code at all, only employee associate with customer, in this case I need to assign employee name as manager (to be accurate responsible)

Comment: correct :)

if manager code exist, assign manager's name to responsible (changed in the original post) column, if no manager code, assign whatever code it is (empl name)

Comment: thank you very much for your time on this, however it doesn't work for me (I have very large df with a bunch of  cust names, empl names and codes, I need to use str.contains(), because there is only specific part of the string identifying manager.

Maybe issue is in the .iloc[0] part? because it's pulling manager name not associate with  the customer at all.

Hope it's not confusing

Comment: @Yara1994 you need to provide a sample data and an output of exactly what you want. My answer here answers your question as written in OP. If you want something else, edit your question to include how it doesn't work. If your question completely changes this current question, maybe post a new question.

Comment: what is the 'mask'?

Comment: last question.
If I have a multiple manager codes (for example manager_1, manager_2, supervisor) and they unique to each employee.
How can I implement it in the code to catch 'supervisor' as well together with 'manager'.
Should I use .isin or anything else?

Comment: @Yara1994 You need 2 separate masks to catch each case because `str.contains` creates a boolean array.