# Assign value to a new column for all rows associate with unique value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I need to assign name to a new 'responsible' column for all rows associate with customer.

If part of the string in 'codes' consist 'manager', manager's name should be assigned to the 'responsible' column. If there is no 'manager' in the codes column, 'responsible' columns should be populated with the 'empl_name' associate with the row.

I assume case and group by should be used?

table looks like:

```
cust_name   empl_name      codes

john         mike       empl, office                
liza         nick       manager_1, remote             
john         kate       empl, remote                
john         mike       empl, remote                
liza         mike       empl, office                
david        kate       empl, remote                
john         mike       empl, remote                
liza         mike       empl, office                
david        mike       empl, remote 
chris        jennifer   manager_2, office
```

output should be:

```
cust_name   empl_name      codes                responsible

john         mike       empl, office                mike
liza         nick       manager_1, remote           nick
john         kate       empl, remote                kate
john         mike       empl, remote                mike
liza         mike       empl, office                nick
david        kate       empl, remote                kate
john         mike       empl, remote                mike
liza         mike       empl, office                nick
david        mike       empl, remote                mike
chris        jennifer   manager_2, office           jennifer
```

My code (googled everything):

```
SELECT  
        c.cust_name,
        e.emp_name,
        a.codes,

FROM Billing as b

--- Code Labels in 1 single row, separated by comma

OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((
    (SELECT ', ' + y.CodeLabelName
    FROM CodeToLabelBridge x
    JOIN CodeLabel y
    ON y.CodeLabelId = x.CodeLabelId
    WHERE x.CodeId = b.billing_code_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')),1,1,''
    ) AS codes
    ) AS a

--- JOINS

JOIN Client as c 
    ON (b.billing_cust_id = c.cust_id)
JOIN Employer as e 
    ON (b.billing_emp_id = e.emp_id)
JOIN Code as sc
    ON (b.billing_code_id = sc.codes_id)


--- Table with Client and associate Manager

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT * , 
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY t.cust_name, t.empl_name ORDER BY t.cust_name desc) AS [rn]
  FROM t
  WHERE t.codes LIKE '%manager%'
) 
Select cust_name, empl_name from cte WHERE [rn] = 1
```

Then I'm stuck. I thought to JOIN cte table and main table on 'cust_name' field, however having issues with that.

Comment: Your sample data and desired results don't make sense, the 2 rows with "manager" in codes still show the same name as the row. Then some other odd rows show a different name, but with no indication as to where its pulled from?

Comment: I don't know if you familiar with python, but here is the link for the same question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70659271/assign-actual-value-after-groupby-transform-to-all-rows-associate-with-it-pytho.
Each customer can have multiple associate employees, that worked with him (codes column are employee's labels (regular employee, manager; work from home or in the office, etc.). I need to find responsible person, who worked with customer. If manager worked with customer, than all rows has manager as responsible for this specific client. If not, responsible = regular empl

Comment: `.. a.codes, 
isnull(max(case when a.codes like '%manager%' then e.empl_name end) over(partition by c.cust_name), e.empl_name) as responsible 
FROM Billing as b..`

Comment: Thank You very much, @Iptr. Your code works as expected.
Have 1 more question...If I want to have a ServiceDate column as a separator. What I mean, assign responsible person based on ServiceDate. How could I implement it? Example: Today client was served by both manager and regular employee, therefore responsible will be manager. Yesterday same customer was served ONLY by employee (or multiple employees), therefore yesterdays' responsible person(s) will be employee(s).
Thank You :)

Comment: Use the date in the partition by? `over(partition by c.cust_name, datexyz),`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get who is 'ultimately' responsible for a customer, if the data has a row for each contact/rep the customer has, and showing the manager, if exists. This (assuming that your table is Tbl) would do that:

```
select 
a.*,
Responsible=coalesce((select min(b.empl_name) 
                      from Tbl b 
                      where a.cust_name=b.cust_name 
                        and b.codes like '%manager%'), a.empl_name)
from Tbl a
```

I used min() to avoid errors which may occur if the customer had more than one row with 'manager' in Codes.

Coalesce takes the current row's empl_name if there is no other record with manager; because the select subquery would return NULL.